# Yii2 alternative for Yii::app()->encryption->encrypt();

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Need to convert the below encryption function to Yii2

```
Yii::app()->encryption->encrypt(Yii::app()->user->getState('secret'));
```

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-cryptography#encryption-and-decryption

Answer (score 0):

You may use `"bestyii/yii2-encrypter": "*"` for encryption